# SWFObject Flash not showing

Tags: object, static, swfobject

i've tried to get SWFObject register a static flash object, but i wont show it. I know visibility is set to hidden, and that is why, but why does it do that?!

http://manual.businesstool.dk/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example uses JavaScript to embed the SWF, it isn't using SWFObject's static approach, so it appears your question is no longer valid.

BTW, you can simplify your code by eliminating the redundant hasFlashPlayerVersion check and by using SWFObject's [callback function](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/the-callback-function/).

Current:

```
if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("6.0.0")) {
   var fn = function() {
      swfobject.embedSWF("http://manual.businesstool.dk/gfx/flash/oprettelse-af-kunde.swf", "myReplace", "560px", "340px", "9.0.0");
      var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myReplace");
      swffit.fit("myReplace");
      console.log(obj);
   };
   swfobject.addLoadEvent(fn);
}
```

.

Simplified:

```
var mycallback = function (e){
   swffit.fit(e.ref);
};

swfobject.embedSWF("http://manual.businesstool.dk/gfx/flash/oprettelse-af-kunde.swf", "myReplace", "560px", "340px", "6.0.0", false, false, false, false, mycallback);
```

.

SWFObject's `swfobject.embedSWF` method includes a domready check, so you don't need to use addLoadEvent. It also includes a check for a specified version of Flash Player, so you don't need to wrap your code in the `swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion` block.